# QT5.13.2 display GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED ERROR in the application output

Tags: c++, qt, directx, directx-9

On Friday, I started getting this error GR-805 : DX9 Overlay is DISABLED on QT5.13.2 MInGW(7.3.0) so I reinstalled qt and worked normally then today when I started the application I got the same error and I don't want to reinstall qt every time it happens.
I searched on the qt forum but found nothing same on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a Nvidia Driver problem, the newest version 496.13 causes it. And reverting to 472.12 fixes it